# Always scroll on particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have a site with a central div, approximately 50% of the width of the window, with other divs either side of it filling up the remaining space. The spanning divs are fixed, and don't move, nor can they scroll.

At the moment, when my mouse is over one of the spanning divs, I (naturally) can't scroll the central div. My question is this: is there a way to ALWAYS have scroll focus on a particular div, no matter where the mouse is located on the page?

EDIT: What I actually have is this:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <nav id='sidebar'></nav>
    <div id='rhs'></div>
</div>
```

where wrapper and sidebar both have position fixed, and sidebar and rhs are adjacent in the center of wrapper (i.e. margin: 0 auto; to sit them in the middle). Scrolling with my mouse over either wrapper or sidebar does not scroll rhs, despite the positions being fixed (so Toni Leigh's answer doesn't work for me here).

Comment: what is the content of the outer divs?

Comment: Did you try my demo?

Comment: Yes but as per my edit, it's not quite my actual situation unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using `position: fixed;`

The two outer divs are fixed to the screen regardless of scroll position. The the central div scrolls regardless of where the mouse pointer is. You use `top` and `bottom` to fix the full height of the screen, then `left` and `right` to fix each on either side.

You can still interact with content in the fixed outer divs.

Please see [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/2qpo7t5t/8/)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I've edited the question to be more specific

Comment: @jako218 try tweaking your HTML, don't fix the wrapper and put all three elements at the same depth

Comment: This would potentially be a viable solution, but unfortunately I can't change the underlying structure due to other constraints. What I'm really looking for is a way to do something along the lines of calling .setScrollFocus(element), so that no matter where I scroll, it always targets 'element' and scrolls that div. If no such method exists, I'll probably just have to deal with it (Google is particularly unhelpful on the matter, with every single result being about scrolling TO a particular element, not actually SCROLLING that element)

Comment: @jako218 what's restricting you from changing the HTML? to do what you're proposing with JS would be possible but a real headache, there are at least 10 different ways of scrolling the page

Comment: it's alright I've got around the restrictions now. However, even if I now have the wrapper as the background, with 100% width and height, and position fixed, with the rhs at the same depth, set in the middle with a higher z-index, it scrolls the wrapper not the rhs if my mouse is outside rhs. Whipping up a jsFiddle now

Comment: @jako218 what is restricting you from editing the HTML?

Comment: nothing anymore. This jsFiddle proves my point though - I don't want the background to scroll as well, I want the background to be completely static, with only the middle scrolling. I feel like I'm missing something obvious https://jsfiddle.net/c31hfjxd/

Comment: @jako218 looks like it works too, fair enough, the wrapper isn't wrapping anything, which is a little unsemantic (I'd probably call it 'background' instead), but apart from that it works - the principle is the same, it's actually the body (the whole site) that is scrolling

Comment: it is wrapping something on the actual site, this is a simplified version. But yeah you're right, I can't believe I missed that thanks. Got it working as intended now

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8xnp0vqL/1/)

You set the two side divs to be have a `position: fixed` property and by using `top: 0`, `left: 0` and `right: 0` you can move these into position to the top left and top right respectively.

Then you can have a regular element in the middle. The scroll will now always affect the non-fixed element. (I added a background picture so you can see they don't scroll).

**HTML**

```
<div class="fixed left"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="fixed right"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fixed {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://www.6wind.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Vertical-White-car-Banner.jpg');
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.left {
    left: 0;
}

.right {
    right: 0;
}

.center {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 5000px;
    background: red;
    line-height: 0;
}
```